# How to calculate $C_\alpha$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\alpha=(1,2)(3,4,5)$, $\beta=(1,2)(3,4)$ and $\gamma=(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)$ be three permutations in $S_n,n\geq 6$. How could we calculate $C_\alpha=|C(\alpha)|$ such that $C(\alpha)$ denote the conjugate class of $\alpha$ under the conjugacy relation:

$a\sim b\iff \exists c\in S_n\ s.t.\ b=cac^{-1}$

My try: By this theorem:

> $\alpha\sim \beta\iff\ \alpha,\beta$ have same cycle decomposition.

I think $C_\alpha={n\choose 2}{n-2\choose 3}(3-1)!,C_\beta={n\choose 2}{n-2\choose 2},C_\gamma={n\choose 2}{n-2\choose 2}{n-4\choose 2}$

However I am not sure!

Comment: Also, for $C_\beta$ and $C_\gamma$ you need to be a little more careful.  (What happens if you reorder the 2 cycles?  If this is not clear, enumerate the conjugacy class of $\beta$ for $n=4$ or 5.)

Comment: @learnmore : Because there are $(3-1)!$ permutations that have same  cycle decomposition with $(3,4,5)$.

Comment: @Kimball : You mean that $(1,2)(3,4)$ and $(3,4)(1,2)$ have same conjugates,right? so my answer should be divided by 2!? and for $\gamma$ divided by $3!$?

Comment: right, that's what I meant.